# undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass when adding has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

(Edit: See solutions included)
I have a model, Goal, which uses friendly_id. I have it set up to add the username to the slug, and all was working great until I added a has_many_through association so users could participate in the Goals.
I'm getting a undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass error whenever I try to add a new goal now:

```
def slug_candidates
    [
      [user.username, :title]
    ]
  end
```

This is my model, goal.rb:

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations

  # Solution 
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, :through => :participations, :source => :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
  delegate :username, to: :user, prefix: true

  def slug_candidates
    [
      [user.username, :title]
    ]
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
  end
...
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord      
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  validates :username, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16 } 
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goals, through: :participations, source: :goal

  # Solution
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participant_goals, through: :participations, :source => :goal
```

I have also tried using

```
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goals, through: :participations, class_name: 'Goal'
```

The controller (Goal#create) that it says is giving me trouble.

```
def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @goal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @goal, notice: 'New goal saved successfully!' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the participation model:

```
class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :goal
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :goal_id, presence: true
end
```

I get the feeling it has to do with the new association, but I can't figure out how to fix it. If I remove the

```
has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :goals, through: :participations, source: :goal
```

from the user.rb model, it moves on to other error messages, so that is where I believe the trouble is.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. It looks more complicated than I thought as it should something to do with the delegation!

Comment: Can you post the participation model as well...

Comment: I've added the participation model now. And just to be clear, this all worked fine until I added the participation stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem in the User model...

```
has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :goals, through: :participations, source: :goal
```

You've defined `has_many :goals` twoice, so the line

```
@goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
```

Doesn't build the `@goal` object correctly.

Try this instead...

```
has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :participants_goals, through: :participations, class_name: 'Goal'
```

Comment: I wish I had some good news for you. `Goal#user_username delegated to user.username, but user is nil: #<Goal id: nil, title: "What", content: "What", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, status: "incomplete", slug: nil, verified: "unverified", deadline: nil>`

Comment: So  you no longer have duplicate has_many and when you run `rails c` and do `goal = User.first.goals.build` and inspect goal it has no user_id. Is that right?

Comment: Then your `has_many :goals` is broken.  Please update your class User in your question showing the corrections you did for the has_many.

Comment: Updated. Yeah, I believe you're right and I just can't seem to pinpoint how to fix the has_many goals issue. At one point I thought of doing `has_many goals, as:  :something`, but I couldn't find the right information to implement it.

Comment: So show the updated code in your question.  Including the correction I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Unless there's a different suggestion I'm not finding, I updated it with your suggestion. Maybe you didn't see it on there.

Comment: I'm looking at your user.rb and it's unchanged.

Comment: or heavens sake that's still wrong. use the code in my answer! The last three code lines!! Replace your has_many with my suggested code.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I apologize. I have implemented your solution, which provided the clue to getting this solved. Essentially, I combined your suggestion to both the goal and user models and then rails suggested I use source instead of class. It works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the method :user_username in the candidates.

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    [:user_username, :title]
  ]
end
```

Comment: `undefined method 'username' for :user:Symbol`

Comment: ??  Did you do : user_username or :user.username ??

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I had. But when I do :user_username, I get this. `Goal#user_username delegated to user.username, but user is nil: #<Goal id: nil, title: "Work", content: "please", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, status: "incomplete", slug: nil, deadline: nil>`

Comment: ok, add `gem 'pry'` to your Gemfile, do `bundle install` at the console, and then after `@goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)` stick the line `binding.pry` and run the application.  When the console halts at the create method, type `@goal.user` and `@goal.user_id` to confirm your `@goal` has a user and there's a user_id associated.

Comment: Yeah, both of those are nil. But if I remove the bits from user.rb, everything works fine.